# Number of topologies on a set: An expression?

Tags: general-topology

Given a set $\emptyset \neq X \in\{\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R} \} \cup \{A: |A| \in \mathbb{N}  \}$, is there an expression for the number of topological spaces, $(X,\_)$, as a function of $|X|$ ?

I am currently trying to work it out my self.

Alternatively, maybe there are some relation\s on (part\s) of the corresponding sequence?

Alternatively, maybe there is some non-zero amount of mathematical sense in this sequence?

[This article](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2037205) shows that the base-2 logarithm of the sequence is asymptotic to $n^2/4$!

> "I am currently trying to work it out my self."
>   —Dror

Comment: As far as I know, there is no "formula" into which you can plug $|X|$ to get the number of topologies on $X$. On a finite set, every preorder determines a topology and vice-versa, but unfortunately, that doesn't really help you count anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This counting problem is thought to be fairly intractible.  See the following MathOverflow question:

[Number of valid topologies on a finite set of n elements.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8970/number-of-valid-topologies-on-a-finite-set-of-n-elements)

There is also an entry for this counting problem on the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences:

[Number of different quasi-orders (or topologies, or transitive digraphs) with n labeled elements.](http://oeis.org/A000798)

Comment: So... A BIG LOL on my "trying to work it out myself"